# Adding Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Effects.TouchEffect disables button click

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-community-toolkit

I have a Button inside a StackLayout.

```
<StackLayout>
  <Button 
    Text="Button text"
    Command="{Binding SelectClubCommand}" />
</StackLayout>
```

When clicking the button, SelectClubCommand is executed.

To have an indication that StackLayout was clicked, I want to add a TouchEffect (Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Effects.TouchEffect) like so:

```
<StackLayout effects:TouchEffect.PressedScale="0.97">
  <Button 
    Text="Button text"
    Command="{Binding SelectClubCommand}" />
</StackLayout>
```

This effect needs to be on the StackLayout as I will add borders and BackgroundColor on it.

However, adding the TouchEffect disables the Command, it is never executed. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: I think you can try to add `TouchEffect.Command` for your Button to replace  the `Command` for your button.